# Import excel workbook to Mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel

Is there a way by which I can import an excel workbook which has multiple sheets to mysql database into multiple tables?

Which means, lets say

I have an excel workbook with 3 sheets named sheet1, sheet2 sheet3. Headers for each sheet is on the first row. Now I need these 3 sheets to be stored as 3 tables (sheet, sheet2, sheet3) in the database.

Is there a way to do this using phpmyadmin, php, python or any other?

I know, we can import individual csv sheets. I want to know if batch import works or not

Comment: Try file_get_contents(''), see what it displays in the browser. Then $rows = explode("/n",$data);. This is php, so i don't know if you understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way by which I can import an excel workbook which has
>   multiple sheets to mysql database into multiple tables?

If you have remote access to the database or if the database is on the same machine where you have Excel; the easiest way is the [MySQL for Excel addin](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) which allows you direct access to MySQL from within Excel.

If not, you have other options:

1. Export each sheet as a csv file, and then read those files individually to create the tables and populate them.  Other than the Excel addin option, this is the recommended.
2. Use [`xlrt`](http://www.python-excel.org/) or [`phpexcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to read the native .xls format files and extract the information required from each sheet. This would be closest to your batch import requirement; in that you don't have to deal with multiple files representing each sheet.